# How do i view access database ini file records?

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ini

I have a vb6 project. It was developed by senior. Now I want to change the existing code. I am new for vb6. The database file like ini format. Actually he worked with access database. I want to create some tables in this database. Please give any idea to open ini file in access database or any idea to open ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, this is old stuff:

Jose 's VB Tips & Tricks

Using Initialization Files

---

To paraphrase the great American author Mark Twain, reports of the demise
of .ini files have been greatly exaggerated.

While Microsoft has proclaimed the registry to be the proper storehouse of
initialization information, .ini files still have their uses. Among the
advantages of .ini files are:

- The files are easily "human readable" using any simple text editor
   such as Notepad.
- The API code for working with .ini files is considerably simpler than
   the equivalent registry APIs.
- Files can be easily opened over a network with nothing more than a
   basic redirector installed on either end.
- Installation of an .ini file is as simple as copying the file to the
   Windows directory.

Windows provides a variety of APIs for working with .ini files, including
the GetProfileXXX and WriteProfileXXX functions dedicated to working with
win.ini and the following functions for reading and writing private
initialization files:

GetPrivateProfileString
     Read a string from an .ini file.
GetPrivateProfileInt
     Read an integer from an .ini file.
WritePrivateProfileString
     Write a string to an .ini file.
WritePrivateProfileInt
     Write an integer to an .ini file.

Given, however, that all of the data in .ini files is plain old text,
there 's really no need to separately code the xxxInt versions of these
functions. Converting a string to an Int in VB is simple enough using the
CInt() or Val() function, so only the GetPrivateProfileString and
WritePrivateProfileString functions are needed.

Both of these are simple API calls. There is one exception case when
reading .ini files that return a C string with multiple values separated by
Nulls. To parse that string, I've included the MultiCStringToStringArray
function.

Before continuing, you 'll need to add two Declares to the declarations
section of a module somewhere. As a matter of habit, I alias Win32 APIs
with "w32_" so that I can write a VB wrapper function and give it the name
of the API function.

Here 's the declarations section:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function w32_GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" ( _
  ByVal lpAppName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
  ByVal lpDefault As String, _
  ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
  ByVal nSize As Long, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function w32_WritePrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" ( _
  ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As Any, _
  ByVal lpString As Any, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
```

Here 's the code for GetPrivateProfileString:

```
Public Function GetPrivateProfileString( _
  psAppName As String, _
  psKeyName As String, _
  Optional pvsDefault As Variant, _
  Optional pvsFileName As Variant) As String
'********************
' Purpose:    Get a string from a private .ini file
' Parameters:
' (Input)
'   psApplicationName - the Application name
'   psKeyName - the key (section) name
'   pvsDefault - Default value if key not found (optional)
'   pvsFileName - the name of the .ini file
' Returns:  The requested value
' Notes:
'   If no value is provided for pvsDefault, a zero-length string is used
'   The file path defaults to the windows directory if not fully qualified
'   If pvsFileName is omitted, win.ini is used
'   If vbNullString is passed for psKeyName, the entire section is returned in
'     the form of a multi-c-string. Use MultiCStringToStringArray to parse it after appending the
'     second null terminator that this function strips. Note that the value returned is all the
'     key names and DOES NOT include all the values. This can be used to setup multiple calls for
'     the values ala the Reg enumeration functions.
'********************

  ' call params
  Dim lpAppName As String
  Dim lpKeyName As String
  Dim lpDefault As String
  Dim lpReturnedString As String
  Dim nSize As Long
  Dim lpFileName As String
  ' results
  Dim lResult As Long
  Dim sResult As String

  sResult = ""

  ' setup API call params
  nSize = 256
  lpReturnedString = Space$(nSize)
  lpAppName = psAppName
  lpKeyName = psKeyName
  ' check for value in file name
  If Not IsMissing(pvsFileName) Then
    lpFileName = CStr(pvsFileName)
  Else
    lpFileName = "win.ini"
  End If
  ' check for value in optional pvsDefault
  If Not IsMissing(pvsDefault) Then
    lpDefault = CStr(pvsDefault)
  Else
    lpDefault = ""
  End If
  ' call
  ' setup loop to retry if result string too short
  Do
    lResult = w32_GetPrivateProfileString( _
        lpAppName, lpKeyName, lpDefault, lpReturnedString, nSize, lpFileName)
    ' Note: See docs for GetPrivateProfileString API
    ' the function returns nSize - 1 if a key name is provided but the buffer is too small
    ' the function returns nSize - 2 if no key name is provided and the buffer is too small
    ' we test for those specific cases - this method is a bit of hack, but it works.
    ' the result is that the buffer must be at least three characters longer than the
    ' longest string(s)
    If (lResult = nSize - 1) Or (lResult = nSize - 2) Then
      nSize = nSize * 2
      lpReturnedString = Space$(nSize)
    Else
      sResult = Left$(lpReturnedString, lResult)
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

  GetPrivateProfileString = sResult

End Function
```

Here 's WritePrivateProfileString:

```
Public Function WritePrivateProfileString( _
  psApplicationName As String, _
  psKeyName As String, _
  psValue As String, _
  psFileName As String) As Boolean
'********************
' Purpose:    Write a string to an ini file
' Parameters: (Input Only)
'   psApplicationName - the ini section name
'   psKeyName - the ini key name
'   psValue - the value to write to the key
'   psFileName - the ini file name
' Returns:    True if successful
' Notes:
'   Path defaults to windows directory if the file name
'   is not fully qualified
'********************

  Dim lResult As Long
  Dim fRV As Boolean

  lResult = w32_WritePrivateProfileString( _
      psApplicationName, _
      psKeyName, _
      psValue, _
      psFileName)
  If lResult <> 0 Then
    fRV = True
  Else
    fRV = False
  End If

  WritePrivateProfileString = fRV

End Function
```

And finally, here's MultiCStringToStringArray:

```
Public Sub MultiCStringToStringArray(psMultiCString As String, psaStrings() As String)
'Created: Joe Garrick 01/06/97 9:28 AM
'********************
' Purpose:    Convert a multi-string C string to an array of strings
' Parameters:
'   (Input)
'   psMultiCString - the multiple C string
'   (Output)
'   psaStrings - returned array of strings
' Notes:
'   The original array should be empty and ReDim-able
'********************

  Dim iNullPos As Integer
  Dim iPrevPos As Integer
  Dim iIdx As Integer

  ' initialize array, setting first element to a zero-length string
  iIdx = 0
  ReDim psaStrings(0 To iIdx + 1)
  psaStrings(iIdx + 1) = ""

  Do
    ' find null char
    iNullPos = InStr(iPrevPos + 1, psMultiCString, vbNullChar)
    ' double null encountered if next pos is old pos + 1
    If iNullPos > iPrevPos + 1 Then
      ' assing to the string array
      psaStrings(iIdx) = Mid$(psMultiCString, (iPrevPos + 1), ((iNullPos - 1) - iPrevPos))
      iIdx = iIdx + 1
      ReDim Preserve psaStrings(0 To iIdx)
      iPrevPos = iNullPos
    Else
      ' double null found, remove last (empty) element and exit
      ReDim Preserve psaStrings(0 To iIdx - 1)
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

End Sub
```

that 's all there is to coding .ini files.

Notes

- Check the SDK documentation for the specifics of behavior of these
   functions.
- If you send a zero-length string to the write function, the key is
   removed.
- If you attempt to write a value for a key that does not exist or a
   section that does not exist, the key or section will be created.
- Despite Microsoft's portrayal of the registry as the central
   repository for configuration information under Win95, win.ini and
   system.ini are still used, so exercise caution when working with these
   files (in other words, make a backup before you experiment).
- GetPrivateProfileString returns the requested data, but
   WritePrivateProfileString returns a boolean indicating success or
   failure. While GetPrivateProfileString is highly reliable, it could
   easily be modified to return a Boolean or some other type of status
   code indicating the result.
- If you use GetPrivateProfileString to return an entire section,
   remember to add an additional null (string & vbNullChar will do it)
   before calling MultiCStringToStringArray since that function expects
   two nulls to terminate the string. Also, keep in mind that only the
   key names are returned, not the values.

---

Return to Top of Page                             [Return to top of page]

---

| Home | Jose's World of Visual Basic | Jose's VB Tips & Tricks |
| © 1997 Joe Garrick | Info Center | [E-mail]jgarrick@citilink.com |

---